# MagicalRecord findAll... changed to fetchAll...; duplication of project caused Core Data crash?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm rewriting my code so that my table view is now run by delegation through a standard view controller instead of a table view controller. In addition, I switched from using MR_findAllSortedBy as a data source to using MR_fetchAllSortedBy because it looked like I could more easily set up sections in my grouped table view with this method.

I should preface this by noting that I've not been able to find much in the way of documentation describing the difference between the two aforementioned MagicalRecord operations, except that the MR_findAll methods return an array vs the FetchedResultsController returned by the MR_fetchAll methods.

The trouble I'm running into (besides being green and generally nervous with this stuff) is that the app exits when I click the "Save" button after adding a new list item, with this message:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'ListActivity''*

Here's the code for the Save method:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    ListActivity * thisActivity = [ListActivity MR_createInContext:localContext];
    thisActivity.activityName =  self.activityField.text;
    thisActivity.activityCategory = self.categoryField.text;
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    //Inform app
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newActivityAdded" object:nil];
    //dismiss view
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I'm by no means an expert (nor even a competent) debugger, but the problem appears to be in this section of code (in the NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m file):

```
+ (NSString *) MR_bestGuessAtAnEntityName
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(entityName)])
    {
        return [self performSelector:@selector(entityName)];
    }
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}

+ (NSEntityDescription *) MR_entityDescriptionInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSString *entityName = [self MR_bestGuessAtAnEntityName];
    return [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
}

+ (NSEntityDescription *) MR_entityDescription
{
    return [self MR_entityDescriptionInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];
}
```

Here's my setup of the MagicalRecord/CoreData stack:

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MRExample2.sqlite"];

    return YES;
}
```

...and

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
}
```

And here's the whole enchilada from the HomeViewController.m file (the table view delegate):

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "ListActivity.h"
#import "AddActivityViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()


@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationNewActivityAdded:) name:@"newActivityAdded" object:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) notificationNewActivityAdded:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self refreshData];
}


#pragma mark tableview delegate stuff

#pragma mark tableview data source stuff

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.frc sections] count];
}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        int rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        return rows;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    ListActivity *activity = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = activity.activityName;

    return cell;
}


-(void) refreshData
{
    self.frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"activityName" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"activityCategory" delegate:nil inContext:self.moc];
}

@end
```

Also, there is indeed an entity named "ListActivity," and I regenerated the subclass files to be sure they were recognized.

Sorry for the length, but I wanted to give as clear a picture of the issue as I can manage.

To clarify my questions:

1) Why is MR/CD not finding the entity "ListActivity?"

2) Can anyone spot any nooby idiocies in my code?

3) Finally, if anyone knows where there's a tut or documentation that gives a method by method comparison demonstrating when and how to choose which exact MR method, I'd sure appreciate it. It wasn't for lack of trying that I came up empty. I literally did dozens of searches both on SO and on the web over the past 2 days, but there just doesn't seem to be much out there. Shame, because MR is such a powerful, clean interface to CD.

Oh, is it possible to be notified via email when there's an answer to my question? I've registered my email address, and thought I understood that would take care of it, but find that I have to return to my question page manually to see if anyone has answered.

Many thanks!